# How to find an issue when using foreign JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications, web, twitter-bootstrap-3

My problem is quite generic: I know that I have a JavaScript issue somewhere. Now I don't know how to start searching where the problem could be. Usually I use the Firefox built-in or the Firebug Debugger. I know how to use it in general. But what I don't know is where to start. Where should I set breakpoints? I often have this kind of problem.

As an example which is my current problem: I have a page with an unordered list. Every second list item is empty for some reason. I can see that the page gets loaded with proper list items. But then some JavaScript seems to add those empty items. It's a Yii application that inserts some JavaScript directly into the HTML but let the browser also load jquery.js, bootstrap.js and yii.js. I haven't added any own JavaScript.

Now, as I said, I don't know where to start to find the problem. It might be that I have done something wrong with some configuration. But it could also be bug. I just want to figure it out somehow.

With my current issue, the best would be to have a breakpoint on a function like onInsertEmptyListItemToCounfuseDeveloper() ...

I don't want a solution to my current issue. I'd like to know in general, where and how to start finding JavaScript related problems. Especially, with third-party JS. With some applications (CMS, shops,...) there are sometimes a lot of JS files. This makes it more worser.

I hope this question is answerable and you can provide some experiences.

Answer (score 1):

Not speaking 'bout the CMS right now, but in general my method is

1) If you did not add any of your onw scripts, just 3rd party, delete them all of your project e.g.
You've added jquery.js, bootstrap.js, yii.js so you remove them and then you test if all works fine, if so, add first one, for me it would've been jquery.js, test again, if no bug visible add second and so on. In this case you'll see in which file is some bug or sort of unexpected behaviour.

2) Here is the worst part, in the found file you should find the problem part. So, download the full version, not production, open it in editor, and start searching... The good news are that you don't have to look  through all file, just find the event listeners in your devtolls or firebug and follow them.

**All of this is just my experience** , so if someone know better methods, I would like to hear 'em too.

Comment: This helped me to find out that I didn't have an js problem at all. After removing all js files the problem was still there. Then I found that the problem was wrong closing tag (<li> instead of </li>, wrongly corrected by the browser). Thank you for sharing your way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on the code.  Generally, if I have a function that is suspicious, I put breakpoints or console.log() at the beginning and end of the function and see if both are executed.  Then I follow the logic down to figure out which piece is broken.  It really depends on the code though.